# Policy default template parameter fails when deducing template parameter value from concept

Tags: c++, templates, policy-based-design

I got some code working where the first template parameter was deduced from the second predicate template parameter [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72720101/10360134). The solution to the former question (deducing the argument type from `std::function` + using a deduction guide) got me reasonably far for my use case.

Now I want to extend it by adding a Policy class to the list of template parameters. Since I would like to put a default policy, it should be at the end of the template parameter list. I tried to modify the solution accordingly, but the compiler fails to deduce the Policy type.

```cpp
#include<concepts>
#include<utility>
#include<string>
#include<functional>

struct Bar1{};
struct Bar2{};

template<class T, std::predicate<T> P1, class Policy=Bar1>
struct Foo : Policy
{
    P1 _f;
    Foo(P1 &&f): _f(std::forward<P1>(f)) {}
};

// Replacement for `std::function<T(U)>::argument_type`
template<typename T> struct single_function_argument;
template<typename Ret, typename Arg> struct single_function_argument<std::function<Ret(Arg)>> { using type = Arg; };

// Deduction guide
template<class P1, class Policy>
Foo(P1 &&) -> Foo<typename single_function_argument<decltype(std::function{std::declval<P1>()})>::type, P1, Policy>;

template<class P1, class Policy>
auto make_foo(P1 &&f)
{
    // Use CTAD
    return Foo<P1, Policy>(std::forward<P1>(f));
}

// Can still specify type manually if you want
template<class T, std::predicate<T> P1, class Policy>
auto make_foo(P1 &&f)
{
    return Foo<T, P1, Policy>(std::forward<P1>(f));
}

int main() {
    auto fun = [](const std::string &s){return s == "toto";};
    auto my_foo1 = Foo(fun);
    auto my_foo2 = make_foo(fun);
    auto my_foo3 = Foo<Bar1>(fun);
    auto my_foo4 = make_foo<Bar1>(fun);
    auto my_foo5 = Foo<Bar2>(fun);
    auto my_foo6 = make_foo<Bar2>(fun);
}
```

Fails to compile with clang 14.0:

```
<source>:22:1: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'Policy'
Foo(P1 &&) -> Foo<typename single_function_argument<decltype(std::function{std::declval<P1>()})>::type, P1, Policy>;
^
<source>:10:8: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'Foo<T, P1, Policy>' against '(lambda at <source>:39:16)'
struct Foo : Policy
       ^
```

Comment: ^^^ Other than that, you are missing the template parameter in the deduction guide and make_foo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8E8xjfav6

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you! So in short, if i have to precise the policy argument, I have to define all the others?! I have 2 more questions to get a better grasp of what is happening: why should'nt we use `Foo<typename single_function_argument_t` (the `typename` causes a compilation error), and what does the syntax in the deducation guide (the arrow `->` ) mean?